# How do I call an API using (Spring) webClient with a @JsonView-filtered DTO?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webclient, json-view

I have dived into the documentation, but only find circular references to the mechanical aspects of the use of `webCleint`, without any concrete examples… And nothing that merges it with the use of `@JsonView`.

I have a microservice that accepts a DTO from the client, performs basic validation, then wants to pass it on to another microservice. But, in passing it on, I want to strip out fields, per a JsonView.

**Basic User DTO**

```
    @JsonView({Views.Incoming.class,Views.Internal.class})
    private String email;
    @JsonView({Views.Incoming.class,Views.Internal.class})
    private String password;
    @JsonView(Views.Incoming.class)
    private String passwordCheck  //validated as matching in first service, not needed when handed off.
```

How do I a) actually build a `webClient`, make a request with it, and return a usable result, and b) give it my DTO filtered by `@JsonView(Views.Internal.class)`?

(The documentation about `webClient` itself is confusing, in that it suggests that a separate one is needed for each request (differentiating it from `restTemplate`), but the examples I have found instantiate one as static in the sercive class…)

Comment: I think it is not possible as you would need to get access to objectWriter from objectMapper at the time of deserialization in webClient

Comment: Thanks @Nick. That would explain why I've not seen anything about using them together (despite it being such an obvious usecase).

Comment: you can try adding mixIns to objectMapper instead of working with views, it is also an option to add/ignore fields in mapping. See [link](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations#jackson-mixin-annotations)

Comment: Interesting theory, @Nick. Except that example shows how to exclude properties that are of a specific class. As I want to exclude one instance of `String` amongst several, that won't work either.